# Dynamic memory allocation dual array of texture

Tags: c, sdl-2

I would like to create a dual array of texture with the dynamic memory allocation, but, my program crash during the second initialization of them.

To add, I don't know what to write like argument in my fonction because I don't know the length of the last array.

I have two kind of levels. The levels of the adventure and the edited levels.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

void initializePreviewLevels(SDL_Texture ***texture, char **prefix, int type, int numberLevels, SDL_Renderer *renderer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *textureLevels[2];
    int i, numberLevels[2];
    char prefixNameFileLevels[][2] = {"lvl", "edited-lvl"};

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, window, renderer);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++)
    {
        numberLevels[i] = 10;

        textureLevels[i] = malloc(numberLevels[i] * sizeof(SDL_Texture*));
        if (textureLevels[i] == NULL)
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        initializePreviewLevels(textureLevels, prefixNameFileLevels[i], i, numberLevels[i], renderer);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(textureLevels[i]);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


void initializePreviewLevels(SDL_Texture ***texture, char **prefix, int type, int numberLevels, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    int number, currentDigit, j, k, l, numberDigits = 1, i, prefixLength;
    char pictureName[100], end[] = ".bmp";
    SDL_Surface *picture;

    if (type)
        prefixLength = 7;
    else
        prefixLength = 2;

    strcpy(pictureName, prefixe);
    for(i = 1; i <= nombreNiveaux; i++)
    {
        number = i;
        while(number >= 10)
        {
            number /= 10;
            numberDigits++;
        }

        number = i;

        for(j = numberDigits-1; j >= 0; j --)
        {
            currentNumber = number%10;
            number /= 10;
            pictureName[prefixLength+j] = currentNumber+48;

            if (j == 0)
            {
                k = prefixLength + numberDigits;
                for (l = 0; l < 4; l++)
                    pictureName[k+l] = end[l];

                pictureName[k+l+1] = '\0';
            }
        }

        picture = SDL_LoadBMP(pictureName);
        texture[type][i-1] = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, picture);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(picture);
}
```

EDIT : I add a pointer on my fonction. It was a typo.

Comment: Don't you get warnings from your compiler? `initializePreviewLevels` is defined to take a `SDL_Texture ***` but you pass it a `SDL_Texture *`.  Seems like the second parameters is also wrong. So fixing all compiler warnings is the first thing to do.

Comment: I have the warning "division 'sizeof (char *) / sizeof (char)' does not compute the number of array elements" and " attempt to free a non-heap object 'textureLevels'".

Comment: You have not fixed all the warnings. Function expects `SDL_Texture ***texture`  but you are still passing it `SDL_Texture **`. And the `malloc` is wrong too. No offense, but it seems you are jumping into SDL without having taken the time to learn basic C first. It would be more productive for you to review a good C book/tutorial and practice simpler examples, especially with pointers, first.